# How to prevent the libgdx Sound class from restarting the song when using song.loop() in an Android game?

Tags: android, audio, libgdx

I've added music to my Android game using the libgdx `Sound` class. However, when I use `song.loop()`, the song restarts before it finishes playing. How can I prevent this from happening and make the music loop seamlessly?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sound file is longer that few seconds you should use the Music class, not the Sound class.